# problem importing python library into a script used by Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I've been teaching myself how to run a node.js server as the backend for an app I'm building, so im still learning how everything works. I am currently working in VScode. I need to be able to call and pass parameters to a python script from node.js and receive arguments back, so im using `require('child_process')` for it. the problem im encountering is that when im trying to import a library in the .py file, I get an error when running the node.js server:

```
stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\ProjectFiles\backendServer\pythonScript.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have made sure to run `pip install numpy` and the same for other needed libraries (such as NetworkX), I have selected the correct python interpreter, but I cant manage to get it working, and couldn't find answers online.

as I said, just started learning this so the code is very basic. here is the code in the node.js file:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const python = spawn('python', ['pythonScript.py', 'one', 'two']);

dataToSend = '';
python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
  dataToSend = data.toString();
});

python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

python.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
  // send data to browser
  console.log(dataToSend)
});
```

and the code in the python file (literally just wanted to see if it works):

```
import sys
print('First param:'+sys.argv[1])
print('First param:'+sys.argv[2])
print('print1')
import numpy as np
print('print2')
```

Comment: Does your python code works standalone? Did you install numpy?

Comment: yes, numpy is installed. the code is pretty much whats in the post, because i just wanted to make sure everything works